# Add dictionary to a file python

Tags: python, file

Let's say I have a dictionary and write it to a file, how could I extend another dictionary or a key-value pair to the existing dictionary in the file?
For example: `{'a':1, 'b':2}` is already in my file, but, I want to add another dictionary `{'d':4, 'e':5}` to the existing dictionary and make it like `{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4}` instead of `{'a':1, 'b':2}{'d':4, 'e':5}` in the file. Thank you so much!

Comment: It depends on how you store it. Lets say you use json or pickle, you'd read the current values from the file, add the stuff you want, then overwrite the file with the new data.

Comment: Read the dict from the file, update it as you like, and write it back to the file.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is your solution :

```
x = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
y = {"c": 3, "d": 4}
z = {**x, **y}
```

Comment: This doesn't update the file...